# JS refresh while under a condition, stop when not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where certain pieces of data need to be refreshed every minute but the user needs to view / edit certain modals (these need to get refreshed as well), so when these are open, I would like to pause the data refreshes, so the modal doesn't disappear while the user is viewing it.

I tried the following code, setting var open_modal = false, change it to true when a modal is opened, so that setInterval method would not run, and then reset it when closed.  The code when a modal is open or closed is being run as alert(open_modal) returns proper values, but the refresh continues to occur. I'm assuming the if statement is being run when the dom is loaded but the if statement doesn't re-run, so it doesn't recognize the change.  I tried to change to while but the page continuously refreshes and the user cannot do anything on the page. Any direction on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var open_modal = false;
  if (open_modal === false) {    // also tried while but the html continuously refreshes not allowing any use of the page
    $(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#trucks_refresh').click();
      },1000*60);
    });
  }
});
```

For each modal, when opened, reset open_modal value to true, and then back to false upon close.

```
<script>
  $('#ticket_modal_<%= id %>').on('show', function () {
    var open_modal = true;
  });
  $('#ticket_modal_<%= id %>').on('hide', function () {
    var open_modal = false;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The `open_modal` variable in side the `ready` callback is not the same as the variables in the event handlers. If you want to modify the same variable, it must be in the same scope as the event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment by [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) the `open_modal` inside of your show/hide callbacks is different than the one you're checking against within the `document.ready` callback because they are in different execution scopes (more below).

Try this:

```
var myApp = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  myApp.open_modal = false;
  if (myApp.open_modal === false) {    
    $(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
        $('#trucks_refresh').click();
      },1000*60);
    });
  }
});
```

And later:

```
<script>
  $('#ticket_modal_<%= id %>').on('show', function () {
    myApp.open_modal = true;
  });
  $('#ticket_modal_<%= id %>').on('hide', function () {
    myApp.open_modal = false;
  });
</script
```

Here are a couple of reads on scope:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/
http://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/scope/

From the third link (by Kevin Chisholm):

```
month = 'july'; //global variable

function foo(){
    var month = "august"; //private
    console.log(month);
 };

console.log(month); //in the global scope, month = july

foo(); //in the local scope of the foo function, month = august
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Will!  This was helpful in understanding global v. private variables. But I have adapted the code to this and while the myApp.open_modal returns correct values when the page is loaded, a modal is opened, and a modal is closed. The data still refreshes when  a modal is open and myApp.open_modal = true.  Is this because the if statement only runs once, when the dom is first loaded and then continues to execute the setInterval code?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on your question. Yes, the `if` conditional will only happen once on dom ready and yes that `setInterval` loop will just run for ever. Depending on what you want to do, you may need to use `clearInterval` and then manually restart the `setInterval` (perhaps with the `on.('show')` callback). [MDN info on clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Example_2.3A_Alternating_two_colors)

Comment: You answered my question exactly. Thanks for this tip.